# How do I configure JACK audio server to automatically use a specific card?

Tags: audio, ubuntu, alsa

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 studio on a HP Pavilion dm1 4200sg netbook. It's pretty much a fresh install. I try to start jackd server by running

```
jackd -R -d alsa
```

and it fails with output:

```
JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
control device hw:0
control device hw:0
audio_reservation_init
Acquire audio card Audio0
creating alsa driver ... hw:0|hw:0|1024|2|48000|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
control device hw:0
ALSA: Cannot open PCM device alsa_pcm for playback. Falling back to capture-only mode
Cannot initialize driver
JackServer::Open() failed with -1
Failed to open server
```

Running aplay -l gives the following output:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 0: STAC92xx Analog [STAC92xx Analog]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I find that by running

```
jackd -R -d alsa -d hw:1
```

jackd starts successfully. I would like to configure my machine so that hw:1 is the default option (i.e. to make the original 'jackd -R -d alsa' command work). Can anyone help me to do this?

I've tried editing ~/.asoundrc to be

```
pcm.!default {
     type hw
     card 1
}

ctl.!default {
     type hw
     card 1
}
```

but this doesn't seem to work. I'm well out of my comfort zone here and any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a workaround. It doesn't configure JACK server but alters the order the sound cards are listed.

I first entered into the terminal:

```
sudo lshw -c multimedia
```

which showed which modules the two cards were using. They were both using 'snd-hda-intel'.

I then entered into the terminal:

```
cat /proc/asound/card0/id
cat /proc/asound/card1/id
```

Which gave ids 'Generic' and 'SB' for cards 0 and 1, respectively.

I then added the following two lines to the end of the file '/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf'

```
options snd-hda-intel id=SB index=0
options snd-hda-intel id=Generic index=1
```

After rebooting the machine, card 'SB' was loaded into position 0 and

```
jackd -R -d alsa
```

correctly started.

Answer (score 3):

First, in a terminal window, run this command:
`cat /proc/asound/cards.`
You’ll see output a bit like this:

```
 0 [SB             ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI SB
                      HDA ATI SB at 0xfcef8000 irq 16
 1 [DSP            ]: H-DSP - Hammerfall DSP
                      RME Hammerfall DSP + Digiface at 0xfcff0000, irq 20
 2 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xfe57c000 irq 32
```

The “name” of each soundcard is in square brackets.

With this information, you can now refer to a particular device as, for example hw:DSP now you can execute the command:

```
jackd -d alsa -d hw:DSP
```

And thats all, taken from:
http://www.jackaudio.org/faq/device_naming.html

EDIT: added code tags

Answer (score 0):

- First, open up alsa-base.conf:
  sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
- Find the following line:
  "options snd-hda-intel index=-2"
  And change it to:
  "#options snd-hda-intel index=-2"

Restart your machine and try again. You may have to set the proper sound device (alsa) for your programs.